# Python script That I wrote using openpyxl module, How do I optimize it ? Reduce the amount of seconds it takes to execute

Tags: python, automation, openpyxl

So I Have written some python code to help automate my office tasks using openpyxl module, but the problem is I need to optimize it's speed / performance. How do I increase the speed of code execution ?

```
 #measuring time
 import time
 start_time = time.time()

   from openpyxl import Workbook
   from openpyxl.styles import colors
   from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color
   from openpyxl import load_workbook
   from copy import copy
   import datetime as dt

  source_wb = load_workbook("GUARANTEE MASTER FILE (1).xlsx")

  target_wb = load_workbook(r"C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\TEST\GUARANTEE MASTER FILE (2).xlsx")
  ws = target_wb['MASTER FILE']

  for x in range(2, 300):
   for y in range(1, 300):
    if y<15 or (y>17 and y!=20):  
     ws.cell(row=x+72, column=y).value = source_wb['MASTER FILE'].cell(row=x, column=y).value
     ws.cell(row=x+72, column=y).border = copy(source_wb['MASTER FILE'].cell(row=x, column=y).border)
     ws.cell(row=x+72, column=y).fill = copy(source_wb['MASTER FILE'].cell(row=x, column=y).fill)
     ws.cell(row=x+72, column=y).alignment = copy(source_wb['MASTER FILE'].cell(row=x, column=y).alignment)
     ws.cell(row=x+72, column=y).protection = copy(source_wb['MASTER FILE'].cell(row=x, column=y).protection)
    ws.cell(row=x+72, column=y).font = copy(source_wb['MASTER FILE'].cell(row=x, column=y).font)
    ws.cell(row=x+72, column=y).number_format = copy(source_wb['MASTER FILE'].cell(row=x, column=y).number_format)



   target_wb.save(r"C:\Users\User1\OneDrive\TEST\GUARANTEE MASTER FILE (2).xlsx")

#measuring execution time
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. Have you looked at the section about perframnce in the openpyxl documentation?

Comment: I can't seem to find the right answer, the whole code execution time is 30-32 seconds. I want it to reduce to 10 or below seconds of execution time. How do I achieve that ?

Comment: Which tasks take how long?

Comment: The copying / looping task takes 30-32 seconds long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace you long wb.cell(...) with variables. It will be more encluttered and faster.

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color
from copy import copy

source_wb = load_workbook("GUARANTEE MASTER FILE (1).xlsx")
ws = source_wb['MASTER FILE']
target_wb = load_workbook("GUARANTEE MASTER FILE (2).xlsx", read_only=True)

for x in range(2, 300):
    for y in range(1, 300):
        if y < 15 or (y>17 and y!=20): 
            cell = ws.cell(row=x+72, column=y)
            cell2 = ws.cell(row=x, column=y)

            cell.value = cell2.value
            cell.border = copy(cell2.border)
            cell.fill = copy(cell2.fill)
            cell.alignment = copy(cell2.alignment)
            cell.protection = copy(cell2.protection)
            cell.font = copy(cell2.font)
            cell.number_format = copy(cell2.number_format)


target_wb.save()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Making the path to the file relative will make it also a bit faster. I don't think you can make it much faster than this, because your looping trough so many cells.